# Reproducible Keras models

Tags: keras

I know it seems general as question but it is really a consistent problem and I've noticed that many people are trying to solve it: does someone have a final solution for the Keras models reproducibility issue (Tensorflow as backend)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean exactly by reproducibility? You need to be more specific.
By design there are many stochastic parts that go into training a deep learning model.
Weights are initialized randomly; The back-prop algorithm is inherently stochastic as we always do SGD; dropout is again stochastic

Despite all this; Deep Learning models train and give consistent results across runs modulo these stochasticity issues. You can run Keras examples on their standard datasets, MNIST and the like and get the same numbers in performance every-time consistently (modulo the stochasticity)

So in short; yes results are certainly reproducible keeping in mind small differences that inherently arise from stochasticity of the model training

Comment: Yes, initializers, Dropout, those stochastic parts of algorithms should give irreproducible results (with no seed fixed). The problem is that if we create multiple models successively in different parts of an algorithm  (in a loop or other structure), results deviate notably. I guess that keras is not meant to be used for cases such as the one I was speaking about. With the question? i was just wonderinf if there is a way to face such an issue.